# Minolta CLE intermittent fault

Tags: battery, shutter-release, minolta

I got a Minolta CLE off eBay last year from a reputable trader in Japan, seemingly in great condition, but every now and then I miss a few shots because the shutter waits ~1s before action after I fully press the button. This only happens a couple of times per roll, and I can't find any clear reasons why this happens some times and not others.

I wonder if this might be a well-known mechanical fault, or an electronic/battery problem maybe. I use standard LR44, not the silver ones, so I wonder if the slightly lower voltage might have something to do with this?

Comment: Minolta CLE doesn't come up regularly here, so it might be worth a shot to post your question over at the [Rangefinder Forum](https://www.rangefinderforum.com/node/82)

Comment: @osullic thanks, I'll try over there